# How do I turn off X-Ray view in the viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, transparency

I am new to blender and I was trying to make a ramen bowl (thought it was easy enough to begin with). Accidentally, I did something that turned my objects transparent, but I am not sure what, consequently I don't know how to try to remedy this. [image: transparent object]How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You have *X-Ray* view turned on. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>Z</kbd>to toggle it (in this case, turn it off)